# How to pass callback to jQuery .click()? Is a callback even what I need?

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a click event that takes a user to a URL based on a dropdown selection. However, before I redirect the user I want to call a tagging script to capture the selections the user made. This is a third-party script and so I think I'm experiencing some timing issues.

Here is my code:

```
$('#submitCity').click(function(){

        //trigger tags
        var countrySelected = $country.val();
        var citySelected = $city.val();

        s.linkTrackVars='prop3,prop4,eVar3,eVar4,eVar6';
        s.prop3 = 'Visitor Action';
        s.prop4 = 'Home City Selected - ' + countrySelected + ', ' + citySelected;
        s.eVar3 = 'Visitor Action';
        s.eVar4 = 'Home City Selected - ' + countrySelected + ', ' + citySelected;
        s.tl(this,'o','Home City Selected - ' + countrySelected + ', ' + citySelected);

        //Link to appropriate city
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.href = "http://www.someURL.com/" + citySelected;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

About half the time everything works as expected. The tag is captured and the user is redirected successfully. However, the other half of the time, the click event throws an error because the object "s" is undefined. I'm assuming this is due to a timing issue where the location.href fires before the "s" object has been defined.

My question is, do I want to create a callback so that the location.href doesn't occur until after the tags are set? I don't like using setTimeout because the timing feels arbitrary to me. I'd rather make sure that the redirect always waits until the tags are fired.

Do I want to pass a callback function to the click event? Or am I on the wrong track entirely? Any solutions to this issue are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "s" is defined in the third-party tagging script. So I guess what I really need is to wait for that external script to fully load.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action:

```
$('#submitCity').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

However I recommend against intercepting the click event in this way because it will prevent users from opening the link in a new window if they want to. It's better to instead send them to a redirect page that does the tracking.